# Extracting part of URL in string format after a specific word

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have an URL link that looks like this:

```
http://simple-shop.com/products/productcategory1/productsample1.html
```

I have to extract everything after the part "`products/`" into a string, so what I need to get in the end is this:

```
productcategory1/productsample1.html
```

The URL is recieved as a string, so is regex the best way to do this? Or is there a more refined solution to this? There is a bazillion regexes so I'm kinda overwhelmed regarding a solution to this relatively easy problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a purely `regex` solution then here you go:

Regex: `(?<=products\/).*`

Explanation:

- Positive Lookbehind `(?<=products\/)`: Assert that the Regex below matches the characters `products` literally (case sensitive)
- `\/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
- `.*` matches any character (except for line terminators) between zero and unlimited times

Working [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/5bkLJb/1/)

I have tried and tested the regex for C# [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester) and it seems to working correctly for your string.

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex solution:

```
var x = "http://simple-shop.com/products/productcategory1/productsample1.html";
var uri = new Uri(x);
var path = string.Join("", uri.Segments.Skip(2));
```

The first segment is `/`, and the second is `products/`.